# 360° Panorama using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to create a 360° panorama using OpenCV.
I tried this code example and its works pretty well: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching.cpp

```
Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(try_use_gpu);
Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.stitch(imgs, pano);
```

If I put this picture into an 360° viewer, I noticed that the beginning doesn't fit to the end.
It looks like this:

[image]

Is there a simple way to fix this problem?